# Moving UIButtons in code

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have code that says when a button is clicked, the one below moves down. I want to know if it's possible to make it so when the button is clicked again, the button below moves back to its original position.

**.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  {

IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonClicked1:(id)sender;

@end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
CGRect frame = button.frame;
frame.origin.x = 65; // new x coordinate
frame.origin.y = 130; // new y coordinate
button.frame = frame;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BOOL` to keep track of state and store the startRect for moving the button back

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  {
BOOL buttonShifted;
CGRect startRect;
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonClicked1:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
// make sure to set the original button frame when view loads
// ie startRect = button.frame;

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
if (buttonShifted) {
    button.frame = startRect;
} else {
    CGRect frame = button.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 65; // new x coordinate
    frame.origin.y = 130; // new y coordinate
    button.frame = frame;
}
    buttonShifted = !buttonShifted;
}
```